# why google play developer console is showing latest app installs but not uninstalls?

Tags: android, google-play-console

Plays console is showing me app installs of yesterday(27th sep) but uninstalls of 24th September.

[image]

Why I'm not seeing any uninstalls after 24th September?

[image]

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Because in install page, it have direct counter for google play, but for uninstall, google save some datas of users and after some day, that will send to that statistics.

Comment: but earlier it used o show me on daily basis. why it is too late now?